# Compute sum with generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I need to calculate the following sum with generating functions:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}$$

I tried:

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{n-k})z^k=\sum_{n \geq 0}(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-k+1})z^k$$

The inner sum is a Cauchy product, therefore:
$$(\sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{z^n}{n+1})^2$$

Now I'm stuck. How can I calculate a closed form from this sum?

Comment: Let $f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n+1}$. What is $\frac{d}{dz} (z  f(z))$?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dz}(z\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{z^n}{n+1})=\sum_{n \geq 0} z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$. How does it help to get the solution from the sum squared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**: Let $$S(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{x^{n}}{n+1}$$ then 
\begin{align}
D_{x}\left( x \, S(x) \right) = \sum_{n\geq 0} x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align}
which leads to
$$S(x) = - \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}.$$
Now
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \, t^{n} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k(n-k)} \, t^{n} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n+k}}{n \, k} \\
&= \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n}}{n} \right)^{2} = \left( - \ln(1-t) \right)^{2} = \ln^{2}(1-t) \\
&= 2 \, \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n-1}}{n} \, t^{n}
\end{align}
where
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_{n} \, t^{n} = - \frac{\ln(1-t)}{1-t}$$
was used. This yields
$$a_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k (n-k)} = \frac{2 \, H_{n-1}}{n}.$$

**Method 2**: Consider $$\frac{1}{k\, (n-k)} = \frac{1}{n} \, \left( \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{n-k} \right)$$ for which
\begin{align}
a_{n} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)} \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \, \left[ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-k} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \, \left[ H_{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} \right]\\
&= \frac{2 \, H_{n-1}}{n},
\end{align}
where $H_{n}$ is the Harmonic number defined by $H_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: Thank you, but it is still not clear to me how can I get formula for $a_n$ out of the $\sum a_n t^n = \frac{ln^2(1-t)}{t^2}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{n-k}+\frac{1}{k})=\frac{1}{k(n-k)}$